# Highcharts how do i keep space between series the same but increase space between categories?

Tags: highcharts

I have a highcharts column chart, here is the [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/BigSexy/3mrh7uwf/5/) for it.  I want to keep the space between the series as it is -- really close to each other without touching. But I'd like to increase the space between the categories so that it's more distinguishable they are different categories.  I've tried playing around with pointpadding and grouppadding but everything I've tried wants to increase/decrease the space between all the columns.  Any ideas?

```
      plotOptions: {
        column: {
          borderRadius: 5,
          dataLabels: {
            enabled: true,
          },
          groupPadding: 0,
          pointWidth: 45,
        },
      },
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Highcharts API we can read:

> **pointWidth: number**
>
> A pixel value specifying a fixed width for each column or bar. When
>   null, the width is calculated from the pointPadding and groupPadding.
>
> Defaults to undefined.

So in this situation `pointPadding` and `groupPadding` can be not respected but you can create your own function for positioning the columns, for example:

```
    events: {
        render: function() {
            var series = this.series;
            if (redrawEnabled) {
                if (this.chartWidth > 600) {
                    if (this.options.plotOptions.column.grouping) {
                        redrawEnabled = false;

                        this.update({
                            plotOptions: {
                                column: {
                                    grouping: false
                                }
                            }
                        });

                        redrawEnabled = true;
                    }

                    series.forEach(function(s, i) {
                        s.points.forEach(function(p) {
                            if (i === 0) {
                                p.graphic.attr({
                                    translateX: 25
                                });

                                p.dataLabel.attr({
                                    translateX: p.dataLabel.translateX + 25
                                });

                            } else {
                                p.graphic.attr({
                                    translateX: -25
                                });

                                p.dataLabel.attr({
                                    translateX: p.dataLabel.translateX - 25
                                });
                            }
                        });
                    });
                } else {
                    if (!this.options.plotOptions.column.grouping) {
                        redrawEnabled = false;

                        this.update({
                            plotOptions: {
                                column: {
                                    grouping: true
                                }
                            }
                        });

                        redrawEnabled = true;
                    }
                }
            }

        }
    }
```

Live demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/hvqs4juy/

Comment: You are THE MAN!! Thanks for that, just what I needed!!